# TableViewの各セルで横スクロールやページング処理をしたい

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

`TableView`の各セルで横スクロールやページングを行いたいのですが、イマイチ考え方が分かりません。`Storyboard`に`UITableView`を乗せてその上に複数の`UITableViewCell`を乗せ、その各セル上に`UIScrollView`を置きました。それから`Storyboard`上の各`UIScrollView`に`UITableViewCell`を継承したクラスを紐付けました。一度この状態でビルドすると、空のセルを持った`TableView`が表示されるのですが、ここからどうすればいいのか分かりません。`TableView`の`cellForRowAtIndexPath`メソッド内で`ScrollView`に画像を置いたり、ページング処理を施すのでしょうか？または`UITableViewCell`を継承したクラス内で何か処理を行うのでしょうか？下に現在の途中まで書いているコードを記します。この先どういう風にプログラムを組んでいけばいいかアドバイスをいただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController () {

    IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([PagerCell class]) bundle:nil];
    [_tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PagerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PagerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self setTopPager];
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)setTopPager {
    PagerCell *pagerCell = [[PagerCell alloc]init];
    [pagerCell setTopPager:self.view];
}

@end
```

PagerCell.h

```
@interface PagerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *pager;

- (void)setTopPager:(UIView*)_view;

@end
```

PagerCell.m

```
@implementation PagerCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setTopPager:(UIView*)_view {
    NSArray* imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", @"android.png", nil];
    int imageNum = [imageNames count];
    for (int i=0; i < imageNum; i++) {
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(160*i + (160 - size.width) / 2, 0 + (180 - size.height) / 2, size.width, size.height);
        [self.pager addSubview:imageView];
    }
    [self.pager setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100*imageNum, 120)];
    [_view addSubview:self.pager];
}

@end
```

Comment: 段階的なステップアップを検討なさってはいかがでしょう？じぶんのイメージの中にある、プロジェクトの形を、そのままプログラミングするのではなく、よりかんたんな構造のプロジェクト、自身の力量内で組み立てられる設計で、形のあるアプリを作成し、それを発展させて、最終形態に近づけていくというような手順を考えてみてはいかがですか？まず、Storyboardにおいて、テーブルビューの属性を「Static Cells」とすれば、スクロールビューの設置などを、プログラムではなく、Storyboard上で行えます。そうしてまず形を作って、ひとつひとつのパーツを、プログラムに置き換えていくという手順が、有効ではないかと、わたしは考えます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かに、いきなり大きなものから作るより小さなものを一つ一つ理解しながら積み重ねていくことの方が近道のような気がします。そういったプログラムの組み方を今後意識していこうと思います。アドバイス誠にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TableViewのcellForRowAtIndexPathメソッド内でScrollViewに画像を置いたり、ページング処理を施すのでしょうか？またはUITableViewCellを継承したクラス内で何か処理を行うのでしょうか？

後者（カスタムセル側で処理）の方が良いと思います。
cellForRowAtIndexPath内でカスタムセルに表示したいデータを渡して、
データの加工や表示についてはカスタムセル側に任せた方が見やすいし変更もしやすいです。

また、個人的にはカスタムセル側で色々な処理をしたい場合は、別途`xib`を作成してカスタムセルと紐付ける方がやりやすいと思います。  
※この場合は`Storyboard`上に`CustomCell`を配置する必要はありません。

ざっくり書くとこんな感じです。
※セルの再利用とかは考慮していません。

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // セルを登録
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([CustomCell class]) bundle:nil];
    [_tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // 表示要素を設定
    [cell setElementsValue:datasource_[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

- (void)setElementsValue:(NSDictionary *)dic;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@interface CustomCell ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *body;

@end  

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)setElementsValue:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
    // タイトル
    [self setTitleText:dic[@"title"]];
    // 本文
    [self setBodyText:dic[@"body"]];
}

// タイトル設定
- (void)setTitleText:(NSString *)text
{
    _title.text = text;
}

// 本文設定
- (void)setBodyText:(NSString *)text
{
    _body.text = text;
}

// その他スクロール処理等

@end
```

----- 質問追記部分に対する追記 -----

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PagerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PagerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self setTopPager];
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)setTopPager {
    PagerCell *pagerCell = [[PagerCell alloc]init];
    [pagerCell setTopPager:self.view];
}
```

ここの処理がおかしいです。
せっかく`cellForRowAtIndexPath`内で`tableView`に紐付けたセルを取得しているのに
`setTopPager`で不要なインスタンスを新たに作成しています。  
また`PagerCell`の`setTopPager`を不要なインスタンス側で実行しているため、
`tableView`に紐付けたセル側では何も起きません。

この辺りは`UITableView`を使用する際には重要な知識だと思いますので、
基本的な使い方を再確認しておくと良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘を受けて質問内容のコードを変更しました。しかしカスタムセルに現在何も表示されてません。xibで作ったカスタムセルの「Custom Class」にはカスタムクラスのPagerCellが入力されています。もう少しで動きそうなのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？ちなみに「cellForRowAtIndexPath」メソッド内で cell.textLabel.text = @"test"; とするとセルには「test」と表示されました。

Comment: @kojianu 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘を受けてSwitch文の中で「cell.pager 〜」と処理を書き直しました。ところが最後にビルドをしようとすると、実行時に「PagerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];」の行で「Could not load NIB in bundle:　〜　with name 'PagerCell'」とエラーが返ってきました。これはセルの名前が間違っていることによるエラーなのでしょうか？質問ばかりで申し訳ありません。試しにセルの名前をカスタムクラス名に統一したり、xibのTableViewCellのidentifierを設定してみてもうまくいきませんでした。。。

Comment: すみません、xibのファイル名を「PagerCell」に変更するとうまくカスタムセルが表示されました。そして自分の思っていた通りの動作が実現できました！すごくうれしいです！本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

returnのcellがUITableViewCellのままなので、こんな感じでできるのではないでしょうか?

```
PagerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[PagerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示の通りカスタムセルを使ったのですが、何も表示されませんでした。。。なので別のところに問題があるような気がします。